# std::shared_ptr Exception Safety

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I just realised reading [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) that the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` with a single pointer argument is not noexcept.

Hence the following code contains a possible memory leak:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p3 (new int);
```

The reasonning is that two allocations could occure:

- The first one before the call to the constructor
- The second one in the constructor of shared_ptr (This is what happens in VS 2012 for example)

Two questions here:

**Is it true that if the second allocation throws an exception, the memory of the first one leaks ?**

If the answer is yes:

**what is the correct idiom to use std::shared_ptr?**

- using make_shared
- giving the ownership of the first allocation to a std::unique_ptr then transfering the ownership
- Other thoughts ?

Comment: Oh my, an interesting question about smart pointers. I thought this was not possible any more. +1

Comment: [The other reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) already had the answer to this...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> ```
> template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
> ```
>
> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/6** *Throws*: `bad_alloc`, or an implementation-defined exception when a resource other than memory could not be obtained.
>   **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/7** *Exception safety*: If an exception is thrown, `delete p` is called.

So no, no memory leak.

Answer (score 12):

Late answer, but it is better to use `make_shared()` for exception safety, as outlined in 
[GotW #102](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/): The following code is *not* exception safe:

```
 f( std::shared_ptr<T1>{ new T1 }, std::shared_ptr<T2>{ new T2 } );
```

Whereas the following is:

```
f( std::make_shared<T1>(), std::make_shared<T2>() );
```

Comment: Also, the replacement is potentially more efficient.

Comment: There are cases where you cannot use `make_shared`, namely calling new on an inherited type while `shared_ptr` is templated to hold the base type.

Comment: A bit late for the party, but I was here for another use-case when that's not possible: when you need to specify a custom deallocator.  But there is an easy workaround: never call std::shared_ptr{} multiple times in the same statement.

Comment: Another case where you may **not** want to use a std::make_shared<T>() : if weak_ptr that would outlive the shared_ptr are obtained from an shared_ptr made with std::make_shared<T>(), **the memory occupied by your object T will persist until all weak owners get destroyed as well**. 
(Why ? std::make_shared is  - in practice - more efficient than the shared_ptr constructor, because it do only **one allocation** for **both** the object T and the control block instead of two. The weak_ptr needs the control block, so you're then stuck with this monolithic block.)