# Is there might be memory leak to allocate shared_ptr on the heap?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory, shared-ptr

Just read this SO post [stdshared-ptr-exception-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053504/stdshared-ptr-exception-safety)

So following code will not have memory leak:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p3 (new int);
```

But how about following one:

```
func(new std::shared_ptr<int>(new int));
```

If the allocation of `shared_ptr` throw `bad_alloc` exception and the 'new int' has been evaluate, I assume the `int` be leaked.
Does they standard defined the `new std::shared_ptr` need to first allocate memory and then evaluate the parameter `new int`?

Comment: Every time that you say `new` and are not immediately inside the constructor of a smart pointer, you have a potential memory leak. Just don't say `new`.

Comment: So true, be wary of `new`'s

Comment: What Kerrek says. Also, why on Earth would you allocate a `std::shared_ptr` dynamically?

Comment: @Angew, I just want make this up. It is not an real world example.

Comment: A more viable, but still applicable example, would be `func(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int), std::shared_ptr<int>(new int));`

Comment: @KerrekSB,  even I say `std::auto_ptr autoRelease(new std::shared_ptr<int>(new int))` should also have leak, even I'm inside the constructor.

Comment: @ZijingWu: Well, don't use `auto_ptr`. It's deprecated. Use `make_shared` and `make_unique`, though the latter is only in C++14. It's OK to make exceptions, as long as you understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *can* lead to memory leak and it's unsafe. The allocated `std::shared_ptr` itself, should be protected somewhere. `shared_ptr` may throw an exception and you should handle it. `new std::shared_ptr` also can throw an exception and you should handle it too. The first exception doesn't lead to memory leak, but the second dose.

On the other hand, you don't need to allocate a `std::shared_ptr` dynamically; it has no advantages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a potential memory leak.

However, it's a very unconventional use of `std::shared_ptr`. Generally the `shared_ptr` is kept in automatic storage (on the stack) to take advantage of RAII.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can leak.

If `new std::shared_ptr` throws, there is nothing to clean up the memory allocated by `new int`.

In general, automatic `delete` invocations are made only when a constructor throws after a corresponding `new`.

To elaborate, you can rewrite the code as follows:

```
// if 'new' throws, we just get a bad_alloc, nothing leaked
int *iptr = new int;

// if 'new' throws, nothing will clean up iptr
//
// if, for whatever reason, ctor of std::shared_ptr<int> throws,
// its memory gets reclaimed by an implicit delete, but iptr's target
// is still lost.
auto *ptrptr = new std::shared_ptr<int>(iptr);

// EDIT: If the constructor of shared_ptr fails, it will delete
// the memory it is given, though this still doesn't eliminate the
// leak that can occur if the above `new` fails.
```

EDIT:

The example above, and this explanation, were really meant to indicate that there isn't anything special about `std::shared_ptr` as compared to any other smart pointer implementation, or some type that accepts a pointer as a constructor argument for that matter.

In the latter case, it really depends on what the type's constructor does with its argument. In the case of `std::shared_ptr`, it most likely will not throw an exception unless it fails to allocate a control block (if that is, in fact, how it is implemented).

If the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` does fail, at least with the implementation I am using (VS2012), it actually *does* delete the memory it is given.

Answer (score 2):

> If the allocation of `shared_ptr` throw `bad_alloc` exception and the `new int` has been evaluate, I assume the `int` be leaked.

Yes, if the evaluations happen in that order, and the allocation for the shared pointer fails, then the integer will be leaked.

> Does they standard defined the `new std::shared_ptr` need to first allocate memory and then evaluate the parameter `new int`?

No, they are indeterminately sequenced, as specified in C++11 5.3.4/16.

So dynamic allocation of smart pointers is dangerous, not just weird and confusing. Don't do it.